# SQL 'like' not detecting delimited multiple values

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a delimiter string like this: "2,3" which is grabbed from a listbox values which I will pass to my SProc parameter:

```
AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@Mode", DbType.String, 50, DBNull.Value)
                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.MemshpT) Then
                        dbCommand.Parameters("@Mode").Value = .MemshpT   'MemshipT will contain "2,3"
```

In my SProc I have a condition like this:

```
  and Cast(T.Mode as varchar(20)) in(@Mode))
```

Now in my listbox which contains values: 1,2,3,4. If I select the values individually say '1' and pass it to my SQL parameter, I will have all activity type 1 results in my gridview, but if I highlight more then 1 values it returns nothing because the string becomes like "2,3" which (Mode is not null and T.Mode like '%' + @Mode + '%') doesn't seem to be able to catch. How can I reconstruct my delimiter or SQL query such that single as well as multiple delimited values (e.g. "1,2" will return all activity of 1 and 2) will be detected and be displayed in my gridview. Thanks.

Comment: do you want your query to run as: LIKE '%1%' for single value and LIKE '%1%' OR LIKE '%2%' multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(T.Mode IN (@MODE))
```

I'm assuming that MODE is integer data type and can only have 1 value per record.

so your search string looks like 1,2,3,4

the values in your database field mode look like

1

2

3

4

I think you want to use the IN operator not like..

which would result in 1 in (1,2,3,4)